# how to compare two different data frames df1 df2 with specific column ( column w) and update the matched rows column AD in df1 from df2

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1
A   B    C  D  E  F  
1   xyz  y  z  0  1
1   xab  z  z  0  1
2   xyz  x  p  1  1
3   xmn  m  q  2  1
3   xyx  n  r  3  1

df2
A   B    C  D  E  F  
1   xyz  x  z  4  1
1   xab  y  q  3  2
2   xyz  z  p  8  3
3   xmn  q  m  1  4
3   xyx  r  r  32  5
```

expected Output DF1

```
df1
A   B    C  D  E  F  
1   xyz  y  z  4  1
1   xab  z  z  4  1
2   xyz  x  p  8  1
3   xmn  m  q  3  1
3   xyx  n  r  32  1
```

i have tried `df1.combine_first(df2)` not working as expected

Comment: Where is column W?

Comment: Nevermind, I thought I knew what you wanted but I realized that I'm very confused.

Comment: Looks like the merge is based on values in only `'D'`. Does the other columns matter?

Comment: @forgetso here i have given sample data frames, both data frames having different schema

Comment: @piRSquared i am having different schema of df1 and df2 column W has to mapped with both the column and need to update AD column values for matched rows

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes need to match the values of column c and update the column d value for matched rows in DF1

Comment: In that case, the answer provided below should address your needs.

Comment: @JoeFerndz will that works if the schema is not the same for both the DF

Comment: what do you mean schema is not the same? you mean column names? you mean number of records? can you please clarify so we can give the correct answer

Comment: @JoeFerndz yes number of columns and rows is not same

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output I assume that you want to merge the datasets . . . ?

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], 
     'B': ['xyz', 'xab', 'xyz', 'xmn', 'xyx'],
     'C': ['y', 'z', 'x', 'm', 'n'],
     'D': ['z', 'z', 'p', 'q', 'r'],
     'E': [0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
     'F': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
d = {'A': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3], 
     'B': ['xyz', 'xab', 'xyz', 'xmn', 'xyx'],
     'C': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'q', 'r'],
     'D': ['z', 'q', 'p', 'm', 'r'],
     'E': [4, 3, 8, 1, 32],
     'F': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df1 = df1.merge(df2[['D', 'E']], how='inner', on='D')
df1['E'] = df1['E_y']
del df1['E_x'], df1['E_y']
```

Output

```
Out[41]: 
   A    B  C  D  F   E
0  1  xyz  y  z  1   4
1  1  xab  z  z  1   4
2  2  xyz  x  p  1   8
3  3  xmn  m  q  1   3
4  3  xyx  n  r  1  32
```